# NestJS GraphQL custom argument type

Tags: graphql, nestjs, class-transformer

I'm trying to use `LocalDate` type from [js-joda](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/) as parameter on GraphQL query like this:

```
@Query(() => DataResponse)
async getData(@Args() filter: DataFilter): Promise<DataResponse> { ... }
```

And here is filter type definition:

```
@ArgsType()
export class DataFilter {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @IsOptional()
  date?: LocalDate;
  
  @Field()
  @Min(1)
  page: number;

  @Field()
  @Min(1)
  pageSize: number;
}
```

I've also registered `LocalDate` as scalar type and added it to application providers.

```
@Scalar('LocalDate', (type) => LocalDate)
export class LocalDateScalar implements CustomScalar<string, LocalDate> {
  description = 'A date string, such as 2018-07-01, serialized in ISO8601 format';

  parseValue(value: string): LocalDate {
    return LocalDate.parse(value);
  }

  serialize(value: LocalDate): string {
    return value.toString();
  }

  parseLiteral(ast: ValueNode): LocalDate {
    if (ast.kind === Kind.STRING) {
      return LocalDate.parse(ast.value);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting

> [Nest] 9973  - 02/16/2022, 5:33:41 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] year
> must not be null NullPointerException: year must not be null
> at requireNonNull (/Users/usr/my-app/node_modules/@js-joda/core/src/assert.js:33:15)
> at new LocalDate (/Users/usr/my-app/node_modules/@js-joda/core/src/LocalDate.js:284:9)
> at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/Users/usr/my-app/node_modules/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:160:22)
> at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/Users/usr/my-app/node_modules/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:333:33)
> at ClassTransformer.plainToInstance (/Users/usr/my-app/node_modules/src/ClassTransformer.ts:77:21)
> at Object.plainToClass (/Users/usr/my-app/node_modules/src/index.ts:71:27)
> at ValidationPipe.transform (/Users/usr/my-app/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js:51:39)
> at /Users/usr/my-app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/pipes/pipes-consumer.js:17:33
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

I'm not sure why is this exactly happening but from what I've managed to debug, is that `LocalDateScalar` defined above is transforming the value from string to `LocalDate` correctly, but the problem is that `class-transformer` is also trying to transform the value, and since it's already transformed it recognizes it as `object`, which is automatically being call through parameterless constructor and it's causing this error.

This is the line from class-transformer that's calling the constructor

```
newValue = new (targetType as any)();
```

Is there maybe a way to tell class-transformers which types to ignore? I'm aware of the `@Exclude` attribute, but then property is completely excluded, I just need to exclude property being transformed via `plainToClass` method of class-transformer. Or this whole situation should be handled differently?

Any suggestion will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right solution but I had a similar scalar `<string, Big>` working with the following decorators:

```js
@Field(() => AmountScalar) // your actual scalar class 
@Type(() => String) // the "serialized" type of the scalar 
@Transform(({ value }) => {
    return Big(value) // custom parse function
})
amount: Big // the "parsed" type of the scalar
```

The two custom parse functions in the scalar can also contain some validation steps (like `moment.isValid()` in your case) since it will be called before class-validator.